# Why an object can be split into 2 components

Tags: python, class, oop, hasattr

I came across this class `Vector2` which was constructed like this

```
class Vector2:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        if hasattr(x, "__getitem__"):
            x, y = x
            self._v = [float(x), float(y)]
        else:
            self._v = [float(x), float(y)]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._v[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self._v[index] = 1.0 * value
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s, %s)"%(self.x, self.y)
```

As I don't have much knowledge in Python, I couldn't understand the first line of the block `if hasattr(x, "__getitem__"):`

```
if hasattr(x, "__getitem__"):
            x, y = x # why can we do this?
```

I meant how could `x` be split into `x` and `y` because `x` is already itself (that is, `x == x`)?

Also, what is the objective/purpose of `hasattr(x, "__getitem__")`?

**EDIT**: If I instantiated a vector `v1 = Vector2(100, 200)` to represent the movement of an object in `pygame`, I found out that I couldn't use `v1[0]` to specify the location of the object on the x-axis for drawing (with `pygame.blit()`). Why was that, given `v1[0] == v1.x`?

**EDIT 2**: correction of the **edit** above. I was wrong, `v1[0]` (same as `v1.x`) can be used to specify the location of the object.

Comment: When you use `x[i]`, this is shorthand for writing `x.__getitem__(i)` from a indexable structure. The line `x, y = x` is an argument expansion, which allows you to declare multiple values by extracting values out of an iterable (e.g. `a, b = [1, 2]`). So this code is asserts that if `x` is indexable, that you can construct the `_v` attribute by pulling items out of the container.

Comment: Compare `hasattr(1, '__getitem__')` and `hasattr([1], '__getitem__')`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, thanks for your response. But what is the purpose of the comparison?

Comment: @Nemo this is to show you the difference of structures which support `__getitem__` and those which do not.

Comment: My advice is to remember where you came across this class, and avoid using that source forever.  This code is horrible - `self._v` is sort-of a list made from float(x) and float(y), unless x happened to have a `__getitem__` method, in which case it's not.  And once there is a call to `__setitem__` the original relationship between x, y and _v is no longer valid.  Just awful.

Comment: And the line `self._v[index] = 1.0 * value` is actually rather amusing, since `1.0*value == value` for all values of `value`.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I think that assessment is a bit harsh. This code is certainly not as polished as it could be, but we also don't have the history for why these changes have been made. It's very possible that the code is used by external clients and needs to maintain old behavior while enabling newer design choices. `1.0 * value` is probably more succinctly written as `float(value)`, which definitely has potential to change functionality in terms of truncating operations. IMO you should choose the best tool for the job, which may or may not have its warts to consider in your tradeoffs.

Comment: I suspect that the original author is trying to detect either a list or tuple which, IMO, is better achieved with *isinstance(x, (list, tuple))* If x is either of these types there is an implicit assumption that the list/tuple has exactly 2 elements. Never make assumptions! The implementation of \_\_str__ is interesting. Surely it should report the normalised data - i.e., self._v[0] and self._v[1]. The way the returned string is formatted suggests that this code is very dated

Comment: Thanks @PaulCornelius for pointing out those 'interesting' points in the code as I didn't notice them until now.

Comment: @DarkKnight, you're right, the book was first published in 2015. Interesting that the version I read was 2nd edition but it seemed the code was not updated to make it more , how should I say, professional.

Comment: @Nemo If you have an instance of this class, say V1, then V1.x may not be exactly the same as V1[0] as they could be of different types. V1.x could even be string!

Comment: Geez, how can that happen, @DarkKnight? I thought `__setitem__(self, index, value)` would ensure `v1.x` or `v1.y` is *float*?

Comment: @Nemo \_\_setitem__ only affects self._v It does not affect self.x

Comment: The purpose of the comparison was to show you which kind of Python objects have `__getitem__` and which don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code's author intended to support passing tuples as initial parameters for creating a new object from the class, Vector2.

The condition `if hasattr(x, "__getitem__"):` serves as a loose check to verify if the argument passed is a tuple.

For example if you pass `(5, 2)` when initializing an object of Vector2 class,

```py
point = Vector2((5, 2))
```

the code block, `x, y = x` will split it and initialize the co-ordinates as `x = 5` and `y = 2`

Read more about [__**getitem** __](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

Comment: Thank you for explaining the purpose of `if hasattr(x, "__getitem__"):`. Would you please expand your response with my new edit of the OP?

Comment: What do you mean by "I found out that I couldn't use v1[0]", because using the Vector2 from your code, v1[0] should be a `float` of the first argument you provide and it works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was confused myself. I think you are right, the problem wasn't due to `v1[0]` as I just found out (please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76370428/preventing-an-object-disappears-from-the-screen-in-pygame